# What is this Audio DJ Header on my motherboard?

Tags: audio, motherboard, headers

I have a very old Motherboard based PC that I had assembled sometime in 2004. I don’t use it anymore but it still works just fine. Socket ‘A’  Biostar M7NCG 400 board.

Its manual shows a header called JDJ1. Audio DJ Header. Five pins on the connector. However there’s no further information in the manual.

I am curious what this header was meant for?  In my little experience with hardware boards, I have not seen it again on any other board.

What external device it would connect to?

Here’s pin out and a snapshot from the manual.

[image]

Google search did not yield any meaningful results.

Comment: SMB is likely to be [System Management Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus). SMBDT is data. SMBCK is the clock. See also [System Management Bus (SMBus) Specification Version 3.0](http://smbus.org/specs/SMBus_3_0_20141220.pdf).

Comment: I believe (but I'm not sure, hence comment) it is a connector for the audio panel on the case, so your 3.5 stereo connectors are at the front rather than at the back.

Comment: @Kevin, that's a Front Audio Connector and it's a separate connector on the same board. Also it's a 9 Pin Connector not 5. It's called JF_AUDIO not JDJ1

Comment: And INTR_B is an interrupt line, and PWRGD probably "power good". So you have an I2C device that can also raise interrupts. If "DJ" means "Disc Jockey", that I2C would probably control other audio functions in some way - I2C isn't really meant to transfer audio data.

Comment: Did you look in the BIOS menu if there are any hints what this could be?

Comment: Except for Enable/Disable AC97 onboard audio I did not find any other relevant parameter in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Biostar Technical support and here's what they have to say.

As per them, this header is reserved for use by the manufacturer. This is not meant for any user level operations.

As a result they have not disclosed any further information on the same. Here's a snapshot of my interaction.

[image]
Answered just for reference, in case anyone else ever has a similar query.